# Synchronizing css transition in directive with asynchronous action in parent controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, socket.io

I'm trying to synchronize a css transition in a directive with web socket events in it's parent controller.

For example, here is a scenario: User clicks on a product that he wants to purchase, I send a message to websocket server - upon receiving a successful response, I need to animate the product moving to users purchase cart and when this animation is complete, I have to actually add the product to users cart (I don't have access to this cart inside the directive)

Below is the code I have so far. Consider the pink box as a purchasable product, and the blue boxes inside bordered box as purchased products. User can purchase new product by clicking the pink box.

(For demo purpose, I'm manually calling `$scope.purchaseSuccess`, in real scenario it'll be invoked by socket.io)

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.products = [{}, {}, {}, {}];
    $scope.purchased = [{}];
    $scope.purchase = function() {
      //emits socket io message here
      $scope.purchaseSuccess($scope.products.pop());
      //--^--- this is called manually for demo purpose
    };
    $scope.purchaseSuccess = function(product) {
      //success event handler called by socket io
      $scope.$broadcast('purchase-success', product);
    };
    $scope.$on('transition-end', function(product) {
      $scope.purchased.push(product);
      $scope.$apply();
    });
  })
  .directive('testDir', function() {
    return {
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope, element) {
        $helper = element.find('.helper');
        var temp; // used to cache the product received from controllers event
        scope.$on('purchase-success', function(product) {
          temp = product; // cache the product to be sent back after animation
          $helper.removeClass('no-transition');
          $target = $('.purchased .product:last');
          $helper.position({
            my: 'top left',
            at: 'top right',
            of: $target,
            using: function(pos, data) {
              var val = 'translate3d(' + (pos.left + data.element.width) + 'px,' + pos.top + 'px,0px)'
              $(this).css('transform', val);
            }
          });
        });
        $helper.on('transitionend MSTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function() {
          $helper.addClass('no-transition');
          $helper.css('transform', 'translate3d(0%,0px,0px)');
          scope.$emit('transition-end', temp);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.product {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.stock {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  background: silver;
}
.stock .product {
  position: absolute;
  background: hotpink;
}
.stock .product.helper {
  transition: transform 2s;
}
.purchased {
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 2px dotted;
}
.purchased .product {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
.no-transition {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div class="stock" data-test-dir data-purchase="purchase">
    <div class="product helper no-transition">
    </div>
    <div class="product" ng-click="purchase()">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="purchased">
    <div class="product" ng-repeat="product in purchased">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the tiniest demo I was able to make, the actual thing has further complications like timers running within which user has to finish all purchases

So, basically:

- User's click invokes scope method which emits event to socket server
- Socket.io success event handler broadcasts an angular event
- Directive receives this event, caches the received data in a
  temporary variable and triggers the CSS transition
- When the animation is complete, directive emits an event with the
  cached data
- Controller receives this event and acts upon the data.

But this doesn't seem right. Is there a way to avoid sending this data back and forth..? Maybe a better way to achieve this without all the event emissions..?

---

Side note: those who aren't familiar with socket io, please consider `purchase` as a method that sends an ajax request, `purchaseSuccess` as it's success handler which should trigger the animation, and upon completion of this animation I need to do some action in the controller scope.

Comment: Would be great if downvoters explain how can I improve this question... I have put lot of effort behind this question and is happy to do improve it anyhow possible.

Comment: could get rid of jQuery UI and and use `$animate`  which uses promises and has methods like `move()`

Comment: you can add property for product -- this will remove one event. Not sure that it is very smart thow.http://plnkr.co/edit/oHODVrtOn3pu7Q9KbiZL?p=preview